# WebApi receiving model with references (Not attached to Context)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a complex type to WebApi having this on my ApiController :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void DoSomeCrud(JObject data)
    {
        ComplexModel item = data.ToObject<ComplexModel>();
        // Do some logic here
    }
```

My issue is that one of the properties I have inside my ComplexModel is an Entity Framework entity. I don't have problems passing that entity if detached, however as soon as I get that entity from DbContext the model cannot be passed to WebApi as expected.

**My question is..** : Is there anyway to detach my entity preserving my references to foreign keys ? Because I need those references on the WebApi side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not best practice to use model from entity framework as data transfer object (Dto) for Web Api because you can get problem with serialization since models from EF are actually proxies which supports lazy loading and navigation properties (if you don't detach it).

The best practice is, for separation of concern, you should define your own Dto objects instead of using entity models directly from EF.

Simple example, if you have `Customer` entity, you also should have `CustomerDto` entity which projects any property from `Customer` you want.

Comment: My approach was doing this way to avoid manually copying one entity to another. Should I do that process manually ?

Comment: @shaftpolls: You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to do mapping for you